# Accidentally sold the Troopa pin. How do I get it back?

Tags: super-mario-rpg

So I accidentally sold the Troopa pin while playing with emulator on PS3. Is there any way I can get it back on the same run? Maybe buy it back from a seller or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Troopa Pin, like many other items in the game, can only ever be acquired once. And there's no way to buy items back that you've sold. If you lost it, it's gone for good.

Comment: Okay :( maybe in the next playthrough then. Thanks for the answer!